# How do I copy the contents of every file in a list into another file?

Tags: command-line, files, copy, filename

I have a list of filenames inside a file called `list_of_files.txt`.

I want to copy the contents of each file in that list into another file called `all_compounds.sdf`.

How should I do this from the command line?

Answer (score 20):

Don't use simple command substitution to get filenames (that could easily break with spaces and other special characters). Use something like `xargs`:

```sh
xargs -d '\n' -a list_of_files.txt cat > all_compounds.sdf
```

Or a `while read` loop:

```sh
while IFS= read -r file; do cat "$file"; done < list_of_files.txt > all_compounds.sdf
```

To use command substitution safely, at least set `IFS` to just the newline and disable globbing (wildcard expansion):

```sh
(set -f; IFS=$'\n'; cat $(cat list_of_files.txt) > all_compounds.sdf)
```

The surrounding parentheses `()` are to run this in a subshell, so that your current shell isn't affected by these changes.

Answer (score 14):

Quick and dirty way...

```sh
cat $(cat list_of_files.txt) >> all_compounds.sdf
```

**Please note:** this only works if the filenames in your list are very well behaved - things will go wrong if they have spaces, newlines, or any characters that have special meaning to the shell - use [this answer instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/867360/527764) for reliable results)

#### Notes

- `cat` con**cat**enates files. It also prints their contents.
- Using command substitution `command2 $(command1)` you can pass the output of `command1` (`cat list...`) to `command2` (`cat`) which concatenates the files.
- Then use redirection `>>` to send the output to a file instead of printing to stdout. If you want to see the output, use `tee` instead:

  ```sh
    cat $(cat list_of_files.txt) | tee -a all_compounds.sdf
  ```

(I have used `>>` instead of `>` and `tee` with the `-a` switch in case your file already exists - this *appends* to the file instead of overwriting it, if it already exists)

Comment: @Zanna quote the command substitutions to avoid word splitting, like `"$(cat list_of_files.txt)"`

Comment: @Serg if word splitting is not done, then `cat` gets the entire list as one argument.

Comment: @muru OK, how do we deal with filenames that contain spaces, then ?

Comment: @Serg set IFS accordingly - see the last paragraph of my answer

Answer (score 4):

While GNU `awk` is a text processing utility, it allows running external shell commands via `system()` call. We can utilize that to our advantage like so:

```sh
$ awk '{cmd=sprintf("cat \"%s\"",$0); system(cmd)}' file_list.txt
```

The idea here is simple: we read the file line by line, and out of each line we create formatted string `cat "File name.txt"`, which is then passed to `system()`.

And here it is in action:

```
$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3 with space.txt  file_list.txt


$ awk '{cmd=sprintf("cat \"%s\"",$0); system(cmd)}' file_list.txt                                                        
Hi, I'm file2
Hi, I'm file1
Hi, I'm file3
```

So we've done the big part of the task there already - we printed all the files on the list. The rest is simple : redirect final output to file with `>` operator into the summary file.

```sh
awk '{cmd=sprintf("cat \"%s\"",$0); system(cmd)}' file_list.txt > output.txt
```